Loading longer with partionner (parallel processing)
My aim is to load somes big files one after the other (almost 2GB by files).
To accelerate loading time, I modified my loading to use a partioner (parallel processing).
However, after this modification, loading time is significantly longer than before.
Is is normal ?
When can it happen ?
Regards.

No, that should not be the case. However, if you have a constraint to follow  a sequence load somes big files one after the other, then you can't go parallel right? Ordering is incompatible with parallelsim, you really need to define independent work units if you want to go parallel.
This requirement really dictates the performance of the job, I don't know how you can improve the performance here (unless you share more context).

I needn't to follow a sequence load. Every file can be loaded in parallel. I think that I hadn't understood well the aim of partitioner. Partitioner is useful to segment the loading by functional rules and not to launch x process in parallel (like taskExcutor).
IThat's why if I use a taskExecutor without partitioner, it's faster.

The partitioning feature and API in spring batch are designed to be generic. It is up to you to decide what a partition is. For example, if your job takes a single file as an input, you can design a partitioner that partitions the file into slices and make each worker work on a different slice. If the job takes a set of files as input, then a partition could be an entire file (see MultiResourcePartitioner for instance). Every file can be loaded in parallel: In that case, you can create a partition per file.

Another way of doing that is to launch a job instance per file by passing the file as an identifying job instance (instead of a single job instance for all files and have to design a partitioned step). That would be easier to design and think of and also easier to scale.
